# Processing String To Int Conversion Error

Tags: java, string, int, processing, data-conversion

I have some simple Processing code that reads serial data coming in, writes it to a string and, depending on what is contained within that string, it converts the string to an int or char and executes some specific code.

My problem is that when I try to convert the data to an integer it either gives me an error or gives me a value of zero ( int(string) returns zero, Integer.parseInt(string) returns an error ).  Below is the relevant portion of my code.

```
String serialreadbuffer;
int t = 0;
boolean STimer = false;

// Serial Message Display (From Controller)
if (myPort.available() > 0) 
{  // Check if data is available
  serialreadbuffer = myPort.readStringUntil('\n');         // read it and write to variable
  if (serialreadbuffer.charAt(0) == 'I')
  {
    SerialText.setText("INITIALIZED");
    t = 0;
    STimer = true;
  }
  else if (serialreadbuffer.charAt(0) == 'U')
  {
    SerialText.setText("UPDATED");
    t = 0;
    STimer = true;
  }
  else if (serialreadbuffer.charAt(0) == 'D')
  {
    SerialText.setText("DISABLED");
    t = 0;
    STimer = true;
  }
  else if (serialreadbuffer.charAt(0) == 'E')
  {
    SerialText.setText("SERIAL COMMUNICATION ERROR");
    t = 0;
    STimer = true;
  }
  else
  {
    int numberbuffer = Integer.parseInt(serialreadbuffer) * 60 / 6144;
    serialreadbuffer = str(numberbuffer);
    RPMText.setText(serialreadbuffer);
  }
}
```

Strangely enough, if I assign a string value directly to serialreadbuffer (i.e. serialreadbuffer = "6144") it will work, but if I get the same number from my serial port it gives me the following error:

```
NumberFormatException: For input string: "6144"
```

and it gives me that error for the following line:

```
int numberbuffer = Integer.parseInt(serialreadbuffer) * 60 / 6144;
```

I was also having a problem with the string.equals() compares (it would always return false, even if the strings were identical), however I got around this by converting the first character to char and using that to compare.  Not sure if that is related to this issue or not.

I have scoured the internet and have found no help with this matter.  I am not an experienced programmer, so maybe it's something obvious that I'm just not seeing.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any possibility that there's a `\r` before the end of the string? Try logging the length of the string before parsing... or ideally dump the whole string, one `char` at a time, printing the `int` value of each `char` (if you see what I mean) so you can see *exactly* what's there.

Comment: So when I print the int value of one character at a time it gives me 54, 49, 52, 52, 13, 10.  From this you can obviously see that it is also gave me a length of 6.  So it seems to have some unprintable characters hanging on the end.  What is the best way to deal with this, using a substring from 0 to (length-2)?  Are these extra characters coming from my serial data then?

Comment: Looks like your `readStringUntil` method is including the `\r\n` at the end then. You might want to fix that...

Comment: Trimming those extra characters did the trick, it seems to be working now.  I used the substring method to trim them, however as you pointed out, I should probably fix it at the source and use a read method that excludes those characters altogether.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

trim the String before you parse it insetad of

```
int numberbuffer = Integer.parseInt(serialreadbuffer) * 60 / 6144;
```

do

```
int numberbuffer = Integer.parseInt(serialreadbuffer.trim()) * 60 / 6144;
```

you might have unprintable characters e.g. \r in it.

Comment: Unfortunately trimming did not seem to resolve the issue, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @JasonAbbas: Did you just call `trim()` on the string, or do something with the result?

Comment: good point i updated my answer! He might do it on an additional line!

Comment: Good point.  I just called trim() on the string, instead of using the result.  trim() does work.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

There could be some space with the value. Try trimming the string before conversion.

Serialreadbuffer.trim()

Comment: Unfortunately trimming did not seem to resolve the issue, I am still getting the same error.